# WooCommerce dynamically change product price html in SEARCH RESULT WIDGET

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I need to dynamically round up the price after fetching from the database. This can be done easily with `woocommerce_get_price_html` until I search the product in the search bar. The price in the search result WIDGET (not the search result page) is still with decimals and I can't find any hooks dealing with it.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solve it with JavaScript (Mutation Observer to detect ajax result display) and RegExp to change the price. This widget seems provided by the them instead of WooCommerce since the default themes do not have this widget.